# Switch bootstrap columns on mobile view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Consider the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="side_panel" class="col-md-3 cold-xs-12">
        Side panel
    </div>
    <div id="mainContentRight" class="col-md-9 cold-xs-12 ">
        Main content area   
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to switch the order of these columns for mobile view so that the main content appears before the side panel?

Comment: I would have thought you are more likely to hide the side panel completely on mobile (with .hidden-xs) and replace that with some more mobile friendly navigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap is a mobile first platform so change your mark up to how you want it to look on the mobile with the full xs-12. You can then use push and pull to move the column. Here is a link to the [doc's](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering).

```html
<div class="row">
    <div id="mainContentRight" class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3 cold-xs-12 ">
        Main content area   
    </div>
    <div id="side_panel" class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9 cold-xs-12">
        Side panel
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, You can not reorder using `push` and `pull` for 12 column classes i.e. `col-xs-12`. Either change the markup to be able to include the 12 column grid system or use a simple solution using `flexbox` below:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .reorder {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #side_panel {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row reorder">
  <div id="side_panel" class="col-md-3 cold-xs-12">
    Side panel
  </div>
  <div id="mainContentRight" class="col-md-9 cold-xs-12">
    Main content area
  </div>
</div>
```